# In Django, can I set vary_on_cookie globally?

Tags: python, django, caching, session, cookies

When developing a Django app, I can use the vary_on_cookie decorator to make sure
that upstream caches use the session cookie in addition to the URL to distinguish
between different pages.

I have a lot of view functions and all of them now require this header. Is it possible
to specify this behavior once (maybe in the settings file for the entire site or at
least for an entire app)? Or do I really have to repeat that decorator in front of every
single view function?

Thank you very much for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you will want to [write your own middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) and modify each request to include any extra headers that you want included on each request.

Creating middleware is easy and you will probably be interested in the [process_response](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-response) method, as you can simply modify the response and you're done.

To modify the headers of an HttpResponse check out the [docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#setting-headers).

Answer (score 0):

Using`SessionMiddleware` [adds `Cookie` to the `Cache-Control` headers for every request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#order-of-middleware-classes).